# How to instruct breaststroke legs to age group of 8-12?

Tags: swimming

I don't have much experience instructing this kick, and apparently, the kids need help learning the kick. They learn fro feeling the motion, so they are more kinesthetic learners.

Comment: Hrm. I'm not sure this is really on topic here, but not sure if it is on topic anywhere else, either.

Comment: Since I never did learn a good breaststroke kick I’m not competent to answer…